# Cannot start Android emulator from Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: xorg, android, eclipse

I faced a problem recently. From some point of time I cannot start Android emulator from Eclipse with following console output:

```
[2012-07-06 23:19:18 - MyApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '2_3_3_Default_HVGA'
[2012-07-06 23:19:20 - Emulator] X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
[2012-07-06 23:19:20 - Emulator]   Major opcode of failed request:  135 (GLX)
[2012-07-06 23:19:20 - Emulator]   Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
[2012-07-06 23:19:20 - Emulator]   Serial number of failed request:  12
[2012-07-06 23:19:20 - Emulator]   Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

Any ideas what could cause that and how to handle?

Comment: Try updating your graphics drivers.

This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11357860/1419728

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with either your graphics card or driver. To install drivers it is either in the options Menu (in the newer versions since 12.04 IIRC). On the older ones you run jockey-gtk from the command prompt. Hope this helps.